# django template if == doesn't resolve right

Tags: django

So I have a simple template problem. In a URL view I pass one var, called 'style', and I pass a dictionary with a bunch of model info. To get right too it:

```
{{ style }}
{% for recipe in recipes %}
    {{ recipe.recipe_style }}
    {% if recipe.recipe_style == style %}
        {{ recipe.recipe_style }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

So what this block should return is:

Dinner Dinner Dinner Dinner Dinner

because there are only two entries in the recipe model, both with 'Dinner' set as the recipe_style (charfields), and the style is passed through the view and urlconf ("r'^(?P[-A-Za-z0-9_]+)/" which grabs 'Dinner' from a url 'http://.../Dinner/'). What it returns is:

Dinner Dinner Dinner

This is because the if statement comes back false. But why? "Dinner" == "Dinner"! My only guess is a format issues? I tried style=str(style) before passing it in the view, but still didn't work.

EDIT: here's what shows in the shell:

```
>>> RecipeStyle.objects.all()
[<RecipeStyle: Dinner>, <RecipeStyle: Lunch>, <RecipeStyle: American>, <RecipeStyle: Italian>, <RecipeStyle: French>]
>>> recipe = Recipe.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> recipe.recipe_style
<RecipeStyle: Dinner>
```

and it works in the console:

```
>>> if recipe.recipe_style == RecipeStyle.objects.get(pk=1):
...     print "poop"
... 
poop
```

So why not in the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing it wrong. The if statement I had was filtering a queryset passed to the template; dumb, right? I fixed it by filtering the recipe model in the view and then passing the filtered queryset.

Comment: Sorry. haven't been on in a while. I'd like to be good to this community. Truly sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `recipe.recipe_style` is actually equal to `'Dinner'`? There may be extra spaces that make this fail, but the browser will still show it as the same (since browser ignores more than one space for displaying).

Try wrapping with the `pre` tag or repr print in your view for the recipe like:

```
print repr(recipe.recipe_style)
```

Then reload the page and check the dev server console, it should show the string value (in quotes).